# Was there any equivalent of glVertex3f in Direct3D?

Tags: opengl, directx

I know that OpenGL's `Vertex3f` is a bit old but I can't find any information about suitable equivalent for that function that was used in DirectX. Was there any equivalent in DX?

Comment: Once upon a time, DirectX did have an immediate/retained mode, but they moved away from that a ***long*** time ago. You would have to go back to Direct3D 5.0 and Execute Buffers. Fortunately, I never had the displeasure of working with a version of D3D that old so I cannot tell you much more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

While Direct3D had, a long time ago, a concept of "immediate mode" and "retained mode" APIs, the D3D immediate mode was not the same as OpenGL's immediate mode (which is where the `glVertex3f` function sits).

Retained-mode D3D was a scene-graph-like API, and generally considered too high level to be useful. It was abandoned after Direct3D 3. Direct3D's immediate mode was a buffer style API; you'd fill up buffers and execute them. It was an API that perhaps lended itself to OpenGL-style wrappers, but there was never a function in D3D that was precisely equivalent to OpenGL's `glVertex3f` or related functions.

Comment: If anything, I would say Execute Buffers were more akin to display lists, really.

Answer (score -1):

DirectX has its own set of math libraries that has progressively evolved over the generations. See this MSDN link for specifics on DirectXMath

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415571(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)